# Can I rebase without first calling fetch from origin?

Tags: git

Here is the document for **fetch**

> Fetching is what you do when you want to see what everybody else has
>   been working on. Since fetched content is represented as a remote
>   branch, it has absolutely no effect on your local development work.

The following example describes one of the standard methods for publishing local contributions to the central repository.

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin master
git rebase -i origin/master
# Squash commits, fix up commit messages etc.
git push origin master
```

Question>
What if I don't call `git fetch origin master` since it doesn't change my local development work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not fetch, then your `origin/master` is not updated to the latest one. Then your rebase will probably do nothing (except for the `--interactive` part, squash, fix-up, etc, that's up to you and can be done), being likely a predecesor to your local `master`.

But when you do `push` it will likely fail, because your local `master` is not a successor of the real `origin/master`. And that's precisely the point of doing the rebase in the first place, to make your `master` a successor of `origin/master`.

Comment: So basically, rebase will not automatically retrieve the remote(origin/master) to do the operations. It replies on the locally stored remote branch updated through fetch.

Comment: @q0987: Exactly. AFAIK, the only commands that retrieve remotes are `git fetch` and `git pull`. You could do `git pull --rebase` to do a `fetch+rebase` but it just looks contrieved to me.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I don't call git fetch origin master since it doesn't change my local development work?

You will rebase your work onto 'master' branch of 'origin' but in its the 'old' state, the one from the time you last did `fetch` (git fetch, git pull, git remote update, clone, etc)

Lets say that yesterday, remote repository had:

```
(at origin) A -> B -> C [master]
```

You did a clone/pull then, so you had:

```
(at yours) A -> B -> C [master] [origin/master]
```

Today, your colleague did some changes and sent them to the 'origin' already:

```
(at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]
```

Today, you did some changes:

```
(at yours) A -> B -> C [origin/master] -> d -> e[master]
```

note that since you did no fetch, the `origin/master` tracking branch still remembers that 'master' on 'origin' is at 'C'

Now, case #1: you do a fetch, then rebase onto origin/master.

- there was:

  ```
  (at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]

  (at yours) A -> B -> C [origin/master] -> d -> e[master]
  ```
- step 1) git fetch origin master

  ```
  (at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]

                         --- X ---- Y [origin/master]
                        / 
  (at yours) A -> B -> C  -> d -> e[master]
  ```

  note that 'origin/master' tracking branch was updated to reflect the real current state of 'origin'
- step 2) git rebase origin/master now rebases 'd, e' onto 'A,B,C,X,Y'

  ```
  (at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]

                         --- X ---- Y [origin/master] -> d -> e[master]
                        / 
  (at yours) A -> B -> C
  ```

Now, case #2: you don't perform a fetch, just rebase onto origin/master:

- there was:

  ```
  (at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]

  (at yours) A -> B -> C [origin/master] -> d -> e[master]
  ```
- step 1) git rebase origin/master now .. does nothing. 'd, e' is already based on 'origin/master' so there's nothing to do. That's because **your 'origin/master' tracking branch is out of sync with the real state of origin**

  ```
  (at origin) A -> B -> C -> X -> Y[master]

  (at yours) A -> B -> C [origin/master] -> d -> e[master]
  ```